# Escaping dots in database name Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-4

I need to escape a dot in the database name in Laravel. The code I tried did not work, I have this error

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '.`facebook_users` where `fb_id` = ? limit 1' at line 1 (SQL: select * from `"database_name`.`com"`.`facebook_users` where `fb_id` = 123456789 limit 1)
```

Code I have is

```
class Profile extends Eloquent {

    protected $table = '`database_name.com`.facebook_users';
    public $timestamps = false;

}
```

And I query that table like this:

```
$profile = Profile::whereFb_id($uid)->first();
```

Comment: The dot is legal in a `database.table` name. You need to back tick both the database name and the table name.

Comment: in addition, get rid of the .com. in your database name; name your database name with a normal text; try to keep it simple, if you must have a char in there just have an underscore. Backticks are really handy if you want to have column names like count, type, table its good for reserved keyword in mysql. You can live without backticks, its your decision.

Comment: Can someone give example. ?